# Trouble getting the hour And the minute for a program reminder

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a project that shows an alert for when a TV show is playing, but studying javascript and the date I couldn't find anything similar

**Exemple**

The program goes from 9:30 pm to 10:30 pm, what method can I do so that using the current time I can make an if statement to show the alert if it's time for the program or not

```
var d = new Date();


if (d > 22:35 ) {
    console.log('the show is over')
} else if (d < 21:30) {
    console.log('the show hasnt started yet')
} else {'the show is on!'}
```

Comment: theres no date literal in javascript. you need to look at using timestamps in terms of milliseconds since epoch.

Answer (score 2):

You need use `getHours` and `getMinutes` for your case

```
var d = new Date();

if (d.getHours() > 22 && d.getMinutes() > 35 ) {
    console.log('the show is over')
} else if (d.getHours() < 21 && d.getMinutes() < 30) {
    console.log('the show hasnt started yet')
} else {'the show is on!'}
```

```js
var d = new Date();

if (d.getHours() > 22 && d.getMinutes() > 35 ) {
    console.log('the show is over')
} else if (d.getHours() < 21 && d.getMinutes() < 30) {
    console.log('the show hasnt started yet')
} else {'the show is on!'}
```